# how do I replace the text "rows" in pagination

Tags: bootstrap-table

In the [pagination example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/client-side-pagination.html), how do I replace the text at the bottom, "rows" with another word e.g. "products"?

Showing 1 to 10 of 800 rows

becomes

Showing 1 to 10 of 800 products

> Ported from [issue # 882](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/882) on `bootstrap-table`'s issue tracker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This text is part of bootstrap-table's [localizations](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#localizations). English ([en-US](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/master/src/locale/bootstrap-table-en-US.js)) is loaded by default.

**Solution # 1**
Create and include a custom locale

*/js/locale/bootstrap-table-en-US-custom.js*

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.bootstrapTable.locales['en-US-custom'] = {
        formatLoadingMessage: function () {
            return 'Hold your horses...';
        },
        formatRecordsPerPage: function (pageNumber) {
            return pageNumber + ' bananas per page';
        },
        formatShowingRows: function (pageFrom, pageTo, totalRows) {
            return 'Showing ' + pageFrom + ' to ' + pageTo + ' of ' + totalRows + ' products';
        },
        formatSearch: function () {
            return 'Search';
        },
        formatNoMatches: function () {
            return 'No matching records found';
        },
        formatPaginationSwitch: function () {
            return 'Hide/Show pagination';
        },
        formatRefresh: function () {
            return 'Refresh';
        },
        formatToggle: function () {
            return 'Toggle';
        },
        formatColumns: function () {
            return 'Columns';
        },
        formatAllRows: function () {
            return 'All';
        }
    };

    $.extend($.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults, $.fn.bootstrapTable.locales['en-US-custom']);

})(jQuery);
```

It is also important to note, that the localization settings get merged in to the table settings -meaning that you can simply

**Solution # 2** Pass them as an argument in your table settings:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({

    // .. your other table settings

    pagination: true,

    formatShowingRows: function (pageFrom, pageTo, totalRows) {
        return 'Showing ' + pageFrom + ' to ' + pageTo + ' of ' + totalRows + ' rows';
    }

});
```

Comment: how can you cange the active locale? For me its always "en-US".

Answer (score 1):

or you can

```
var $table = $('#bootstrap-table');
$table.bootstrapTable({
                toolbar: ".toolbar",
                clickToSelect: true,
                showRefresh: true,
                search: true,
                showToggle: true,
                showColumns: true,
                pagination: true,
                searchAlign: 'left',
                pageSize: 8,
                clickToSelect: false,
                pageList: [8,10,25,50,100],

                formatRecordsPerPage: function(pageNumber){
                    return pageNumber + " rows visible";
                },

                formatShowingRows: function(pageFrom, pageTo, totalRows){
                    //do nothing here, we don't want to show the text "showing x of y from..."
                    return 'Showing ' + pageFrom + ' to ' + pageTo + ' of ' + totalRows + ' ';
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

based on jtrumbull`s totally correct answer, I would spent a third one:

Solution # 3 use a locale and merge / overwrite parts of them with your own:
in this example, we will overwrite the already defined "formatShowingRows" function.

```
// create an array where you store your own translations
var mylocale = {
    formatShowingRows: function (pageFrom, pageTo, totalRows) {
        return 'Ergebnisse <b>' + pageFrom + '-' + pageTo + '</b> von <b>' + totalRows + '</b>';
    }
}
// extend the used locale
$.extend(true, $.fn.bootstrapTable.locales.de, mylocale);
```